# INSERT INTO LEFT JOIN php error

Tags: php, mysql, insert-into

I have encountered few errors when I tried to modify the code as below. I wish to create a `INSERT INTO LEFT JOIN` code.

**CODE**

```
public function createPayments($item) {

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection,  "INSERT INTO payments (payments.payment_id, payments.payment_amount,
                                                    payments.payment_date) SELECT students.student_id, students.firstname, students.lastname,
                                                    fee.fee_id, fee.fee_description, fee.class_id, fee.fee_amount, class.class_description
                                                    FROM students
                                                    LEFT JOIN class ON students.class_id = class.class_id
                                                    LEFT JOIN fee ON fee.class_id = class.class_id
                                                    LEFT JOIN payments ON payments.student_id = students.student_id
                                                    AND payments.fee_id = fee.fee_id");

        $this->throwExceptionOnError();
//line 81
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'issi', $item->student_id, $item->fee_id, $item-> fee_description, $item->class_id, $item->fee_amount,
                                $item->firstname, $item->lastname,$item->class_description, 
                                $item->payment_amount, $item->payment_id, $item->payment_date->toString('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') );
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);     
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        $autoid = mysqli_stmt_insert_id($stmt);

        mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);     
        mysqli_close($this->connection);

        return $autoid;
    }

    public function updatePayments($item) {

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "UPDATE $this->query3 SET student_id=?, fee_id=?, fee_description=?, class_id=?, fee_amount=?,
                                                    firstname=?, lastname=?, payment_date=?, class_description=?, payment_amount=?,
                                                    payment_date=? where payment_id=?");        
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'issii',  $item->student_id, $item->fee_id, $item-> fee_description, $item->class_id, $item->fee_amount,
                                $item->firstname, $item->lastname, $item->payment_id, $item->payment_date->toString('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), 
                                $item->class_description, $item->payment_amount, $item->payment_date);
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);     
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);     
        mysqli_close($this->connection);
    }


    public function deletePayments($itemID) {

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "DELETE FROM $this->query3 WHERE payment_id = ?");
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $itemID);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);     
        mysqli_close($this->connection);
    }
```

**ERROR**
Probably something goes wrong in mysqli_stmt_bind_param...

```
There was an error while invoking the operation. Check your operation inputs or server code and try invoking the operation again. 

Reason: 
Warning: Attempt to modify property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\feez3\services\PaymentsService3.php on line 81

    Warning: Attempt to modify property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\feez3\services\PaymentsService3.php on line 81

    Warning: Attempt to modify property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\feez3\services\PaymentsService3.php on line 81

    Warning: Attempt to modify property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\feez3\services\PaymentsService3.php on line 81

    Warning: Attempt to modify property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\feez3\services\PaymentsService3.php on line 81

    Warning: Attempt to modify property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\feez3\services\PaymentsService3.php on line 81

    Warning: Attempt to modify property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\feez3\services\PaymentsService3.php on line 82

    Warning: Attempt to modify property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\feez3\services\PaymentsService3.php on line 82

    Warning: Attempt to modify property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\feez3\services\PaymentsService3.php on line 82

    Warning: Attempt to modify property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\feez3\services\PaymentsService3.php on line 83

    Warning: Attempt to modify property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\feez3\services\PaymentsService3.php on line 83

    Fatal error: Call to a member function toString() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\feez3\services\PaymentsService3.php on line 83
```

Anyone here been thru the same situation? Please guide me thru this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Right here

```
payments.payment_id,,
```

You have two commas, remove one.

Comment: ><" Thank u....my mistake. But another error occur: Warning: Attempt to modify property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\feez3\services\PaymentsService3.php on line 82

Comment: $item->firstname, $item->lastname,$item->class_description,

Comment: You'll need to post the code where you're actually setting the $item param. Those errors mean you're treating it like an object when it isn't. Some options you have are echo var_dump($item) which will display the contents and datatype of each element, or consider the fact that you may have set $item to be an array instead of an object.